# Powershell script stops working when ran through task scheduler

Tags: excel, powershell, scripting

I am running the script below as a scheduled task with the user logged on the server. It converts an xls file to csv using the `Excel.Application` COM object. The conversion works, but eventually breaks and I don't know why.

I have the task run the following command which should in theory allow it to run constantly:

`powershell.exe -noexit -file "filename.ps1"`

Any thoughts on what to try?

```
$server = "\\server"
$xls = "\path\XLS\"
$csv = "\path\CSV\"
$folder = $server + $xls
$destination = $server + $csv

$filter = "*.xls" # <-- set this according to your requirements

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true # <-- set this according to your requirements
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]"FileName, LastWrite"
}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {

    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

    $excelFile = $folder + $name
    $E = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $E.Visible = $false
    $E.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $wb = $E.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)

    foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets) {
        $n = "output_" + $name -replace ".XLS"
        $ws.SaveAs($destination + $n + ".csv", 6)
    }

    $E.Quit()     
}
```

Comment: Are you running the task as a user who has the rights to access the network server?

Comment: _"The converting works, but eventually breaks and I don't know why."_ Can you add more detail? Which part works, and which part breaks? Does it work once and then fails 2nd time or works a few times and then breaks? Does it matter whether the user is logged in or not? Task screenshots/settings would be helpful

Comment: As Jeff said, verify the user the task is running as. There is a field in scheduled tasks that allows you to enter a user and password to run as. If it "partially" runs, it may be that it doesn't have access to a certain directory you are trying to convert

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin - yes i am running the task as the user, when logged on, and the user is logged in all the time. the user has access to the network share

Comment: @gms0ulman - converting happens. i drop a .xls file into the folder, it gets converted to .csv because the script is running in the background. i just notice eventually usually 4-5 days later, when i drop a .xls file, the convert stops even though the powershell script is still running.

Comment: I guess you should have your script increment a log file to know which part fails?

Comment: Is the PowerShell windows still open that launched the FileSystemWatcher? If so, can you run Get-Job to see if your job "FileCreated" is listed still? Also, I assume that the script is currently in a state of not working; is that correct?

Comment: @CalebSeelhoff Yes the window is kept open with the -noexit command. I'm giving it another go. In my test environment I have to run the task in 4 instances with different -SourceIdentifiers. Perhaps the application is crashing somewhere because of this so I'm just running one now. I'll run the Get-Job to check status.

Comment: @sodawillow I'll consider that.

Comment: has this been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I was doing something similar with word. I couldnt use `Quit` alone. I think using `Quit` hides Excel. Try releasing the com object by using:

```
$E.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($E)
Remove-Variable E
```

i dont know if you are opening the Excel application but if you are you can maybe use

```
$wb.close($false)
```

Let me know if it works...

Ref: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730962.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396